# How do friend classes interact with each other

Tags: c++

I have two simple class that I made just to understand how friend class works. I am confused as to why this doesn't compile and also would the Linear class have access to the struct inside Queues class?

Linear.h

```
template<typename k, typename v >
 class Linear
 {
    public:
    //Can I create a instance of Queues here if the code did compile? 

    private:
  };
```

Linear.cpp

```
#include "Linear.h"
```

Queues.h

```
 #include "Linear.h"

 template<typename k, typename v >
 class Linear;

  template<typename x>
  class Queues
  {
    public:

    private:
        struct Nodes{
            int n;
        };
    //Does this mean I am giving Linear class access to all of my Queues class variable or    is it the opposite ? 
    friend class Linear<k,v>;
    };
```

Queues.cpp

```
  #include"Queues.h"
```

My errors are

```
Queues.h:15: error: `k' was not declared in this scope
Queues.h:15: error: `v' was not declared in this scope
Queues.h:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
Queues.h:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
Queues.h:15: error: friend declaration does not name a class or function
```

Comment: You don't have classes. You have templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your initial question:

the `friend` keyword inside a class let the friend function or class access otherwise private field of the class where the friend constraint is declared.
See this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) for a thorough explanation of this language feature.

Regarding the compilation errors in your code:
In this line:

```
friend class Linear<k,v>;
```

ask yourself, what is `k`, where is it defined? Same for `v`.

Basically, a template is not a class, it's a syntactic construct letting you define a "class of class", meaning that for the template:

```
template <typename T>
class C { /* ... */ };
```

you don't have yet a class, but something that will let you define class if you provide it a proper typename. Within the template the typename T is defined, and can be used in place as if it were a real type.

In the following code snippets:

```
template <typename U> 
class C2 {
   C<U> x;
   /* ... */
};
```

you define another template, which when instantiated with a given typename will contain an instance of the template C with the same typename. The typename `U` in the line `C<U> x;` of the code above, is *defined* by the including template. However, in your code, `k` and `v` don't have such a definition, either in the template where they are being used, or at the top level.

In the same spirit, the following template:

```
template <typename U> 
class C2 {
   friend class C<U>;
   /* ... */
};
```

when *instantiated*, will have the **instance** of the class template C (again with the same parameter `U`) as a friend. As far as I know, It is not possible to have class template instances be friend with a given class, for all possible parameters combinations (The C++ language doesn't support existential types yet).

You could, for instance, write something like:

```
template<typename x>
class Queues
{
  public:

  private:
     struct Nodes{
        int x;
     };

  friend class Linear<x,x>;
};
```

to restrict the friendliness of `Linear` to only the instance of that template with `x` and `x`, or something like this:

```
template<typename x,typename k, typename v>
class Queues
{
  public:

  private:
     struct Nodes{
        int x;
     };

  friend class Linear<k,v>;
};
```

If you want to allow `k` and `v` to be defined ad lib.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with templates not with friend classes in that code.

Friend just means that restrictions against access to private and protected are removed for that class.  As if the word private in the class was public, basically.

Do try to submit code with one problem and which you understand all but one thing.